# Grid based collision detection setup

Tags: c++, grid, collision-detection, partitioning

I understand the concept of grid based collision detection, but one small detail I'm not sure how to go about. I've learned that constantly adding to and resetting vectors takes up a lot of time, so I'm not sure how to go about storing bodies in cells of the grid.

I have a vector of bodies, so my setup for the grid would be to have something like:

```c++
std::vector <int> grid[1000][1000]; //[x grid][y grid][list of bodies' indices in that cell]
```

OR

```c++
int grid[1000][1000][500]; //[x grid][y grid][list of bodies' indices in that cell]
```

both of which seem very impractical to use since it's such a large amount of data, and because the third index would have to be reset everytime correct? from my understanding, everything in the grid is always subject to change since if the min x or y changes, the position of [0][0] will change as well, and since obviously there are moving bodies, the third index would have to be reset and re-added to every single frame.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do differently, but I'm sure there's something wrong with the way I have this set up or the way I'm thinking about it

EDIT: the size of the grid in the x and y position are also subject to change, since the difference between max and mins can differ, "1000" is just a value I plugged in there that will work for me for right now

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do based on the question, but do consider that 1000 * 1000 * 500 * sizeof(int) = 2 gigabytes!

Comment: @MrEricSir Im trying to set up a grid based spatial partitioning collision detection broad phase, and more specifically I'm trying to set up the grid where each cell contains all the bodies in that cell